# Does scotch tape only use van der Waals forces?

Tags: van-der-waals-behavior

Does it also make use of covalent bonds to stick to surfaces?

Comment: Essentially yes. You can probably upscale the analysis (surface tension etc) but at the smaller scale it will be VdW forces and no covalent bonds.

Comment: Curious, It is *way* more complex. Read here https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/what-exactly-is-the-physi/